# How to implement a socket client to *automatically* download and use a SSL certificate when connecting to a SSL server?

Tags: java, ssl, https, wss

I am writing my own client implementation in Java that uses `SSLEngine` with all its complexities to connect to a HTTPS server. So far so good, but I have to manually download the certificate and create a keystore **before** I want to connect to the HTTPS server. To do that I manually run `openssl` and `keytool` in the command-line.

That must be a way to do that process *programmatically* in the client itself so when it tries to connect to a new HTTPS site nothing needs to be done beforehand.

Comment: most http clients will automatically do this for you.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am writing my own client. I know that other clients do that automatically so it looks like it is possible. I would like to know how to do it so I can also add this feature to my socket client. Editing the question to make this clear.

Comment: You mean downloading a CA certificate to verify the identity of the server? Or something else?

Comment: When you connect to a SSL server you need a certificate. That's how SSL/https works. Without a certificate you can't connect.

Comment: @PeterMel No, that's not true. When configured normally, the SSL server will send its certificate as part of the connection process, and the client does not need a certificate.

Comment: @duskwuff Dude, that's exactly what I am trying to accomplish. Download and use the certificate at run-time without needing to previously download and add to a keystore.

Comment: @PeterMel What duskwuff try to say is that the certificate is provided by the server *during* the ssl/tls handshake, not *before*. It is part of the protocol...

Comment: In any case you need something (some set of trusted certificates) to match the server certificate against. If you don't have a set of trusted certificates, preferably obtained using other, reliable, channel, then your secure connection is not secure at all. What you are asking is "how do I accept whatever certificate will be presented by the server". That's nonsense as it's a door open wide to man-in-the-middle.